# Gradle search local maven or gradle repository

Tags: gradle

I am using gradle and its local repository is at `\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1` which has all the downloaded jar but not my modules.Is there any specific place I should be searching it for ?

I need it as is in `settings.gradle` I am having a dependency path specified like :

```
include ':model'
project (':model').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, './model')
```

in a new project. Also I don't want to give path in that way because if I have a dependency from multiple projects on this project then mentioning path will be difficult and weird.

How can I make gradle search it from local maven or gradle repositories.

Comment: Ignore the dependency cache (the _.gradle/caches/..._ directory). Try to explain precisely what you want to accomplish. `model` looks like its part of a larger multi-project build. Do you want to use it from other builds? Or other projects in this build? If you're not sure of terminology, then feel free to ask. It can get confusing with 'build' and 'project'.

Comment: Like in maven when we include a `<parent>` we give `<relativePath>` in which we mention `../pom.xml` to mention the parent I don't want to do so rather I want gradle to find the path of the module on which it is dependent.

Comment: When you declare a project dependency, you specify a _logical path_. For example, project A might have `compile project(":model)`, which states that A has a project dependency on 'model'. _It is not a file path_. You can then use the code from _settings.gradle_ in your original post to specify the actual file path to the project. Make sense?

Comment: That's what I am doing now which I don't want to do. Imagine if I have to depend on a project which was a mile away like `../../../some/path/leads/to/another/etc`

Comment: In your example, is 'etc' an independent project with its own build? Or is it part of this multi-project build?

Comment: the whole path is the path for the `model` project. It also looks ugly.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't answer my question. Unless you fully explain what it is you're trying to do, I can't help.

Comment: All I want is not give a hard coded path to my model project from any other project in the repository. In other words without using the second line in my settings.gradle is it possible to include the model dependency in my project. I don't even want to know that model project exists at some path. If I give other team members the model dependency `compile project (:model)` that should be more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure what is being asked here, and I suspect there is some confusion over how multi-project builds work. So I'm going to attempt to provide a general-purpose answer.

The first question you need to answer is whether you're interested in dependencies between projects that are part of the same build — as in part of a [multi-project build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/intro_multi_project_builds.html) — or in separate builds.

### Project dependencies (multi-project builds)

Project dependencies are covered in the [user manual](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sec:declaring_project_dependency) and only apply to multi-project builds. They use a logical path, using colons as 'path' separators, to specify the location of the target module, like so:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":model")
}
```

At this point, Gradle needs to know where ":model" exists on the file system. There's no getting around that. You have a few options:

1. Follow the convention of directory structure matching the logical path structure, i.e. have a *MyBigProject/model* directory containing the ":model" child project
2. Specify the file path of ":model" in *settings.gradle*, e.g. with `project(":model").projectDir = new File(rootDir, "unusual/path/to/model")`
3. Automate the discovery of projects

The most common approach is the first one. The second is not unusual, particularly if you want to put child projects into a separate directory, like *subprojects* — something the build of Gradle itself does. I haven't seen the last option done, and I don't know whether it runs into problems.

For the sake of completeness, and at your own risk if you use something like it, here's an example of automatic discovery of projects in the *settings.gradle* file:

```
rootDir.eachDir { File dir ->
    if ("build.gradle" in dir.listFiles()*.name) {
        include dir.name
    }
}
```

This fragment basically looks for directories within the root project folder that have a *build.gradle* file in them and adds them as child projects. The child projects' directory names become the projects' names.

It's not particularly clever, and you should really use different names for the build files, but it may give you some ideas to work with.

### Non-project dependencies

As with project dependencies, Gradle needs to know where to get the corresponding JAR or other form of artifact for a specified module. You normally specify Maven Central or something similar for this, but there are other useful, but less common, options:

1. Copy a project's artifacts into the local Maven repository — both the [Maven Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html) and [Maven Publish Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) support this
2. Publish to a Maven-compatible repository using a *file://* URL rather than an HTTP/HTTPS one, which protects your projects from corruption of Maven Local

Worth noting is that Gradle supports [*composite builds*](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html) that allow you to substitute a normal dependency with (effectively) a project dependency from another build. So if *model* were part of a separate build but you had the source code and build locally, you could make changes and immediately test them in another build's project without going through the whole "install" intermediate step that's common in the Maven world (and Gradle pre-composite-builds).

Hope all this makes sense.